# Gradle dependency conflict between library and project android

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am building an Android project. With the following gradle configuration. Everything was working fine. Until I tried adding [lottie-android](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android) library in the project.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ignite.a01hw909350.kolamdemo"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    aaptOptions {
        noCompress 'KARMarker'
        noCompress 'armodel'
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile project(':KudanAR')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'nl.dionsegijn:konfetti:1.0.2'
    compile 'me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.4.1'
    compile 'io.palaima:smoothbluetooth:0.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.3.0'
    compile 'com.flurgle:camerakit:0.9.17'
    compile 'com.github.zhukic:sectioned-recyclerview:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.4.3'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.4.0'
    compile 'org.rajawali3d:rajawali:1.1.668@aar'
    compile 'com.tapadoo.android:alerter:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.github.GoodieBag:ProtractorView:v1.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.stepstone.stepper:material-stepper:3.3.0'
    compile 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.4.3'
    compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.4'
    compile 'com.github.apl-devs:appintro:v4.2.2'
    compile 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.2.5'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

When I add `compile 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.2.5'` in the gradle and compile. I am getting below error.

```
Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0
```

**I dont wanna update my sdk currently. How can avoid this error ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your application build.gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

And then add the dependencie(s):

```
dependencies {
    def supportLibrariesVersion = '26.1.0'

    compile "com.android.support:support-compat:${supportLibrariesVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${supportLibrariesVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${supportLibrariesVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:${supportLibrariesVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:design:${supportLibrariesVersion}"
}
```

Also, you've to do the following modifications to make it works:

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
```

Comment: Getting this error after doing the above changes.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46443975/manifest-merger-failed-with-multiple-errors-while-updating-to-api-26-in-android/

Comment: I've updated my answer. Let me know if it solves your issue.

Comment: I tried the same. But I am getting some weird error. Please check my another question related to this. I am getting some Merger Manifest error.
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46443975/manifest-merger-failed-with-multiple-errors-while-updating-to-api-26-in-android/

Comment: I just added Lottie to my own project and had to do some more modifications to make it works. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. it worked. Are you using Android Studio 3.0 or Android Studio 2.3.3 ?

Comment: Android Studio 2.3.3 until version 3 is officially released.

Comment: @Benjamin I have similar problem, as Herin said She use sdk version 25 and she said "I dont wanna update my sdk currently. How can avoid this error ?" but according to your answer, upgrade sdk version to 26. So we must upgrade the sdk otherwise we can not use lottie  2.2.x on sdks before  26, right? Is there any reference lottie documentation to show which sdk version required for lottie versions?

Comment: @erhun yes but you cannot avoid this error and not upgrading your sdk at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess but maybe it fails because the appcompat-v7:26.1.0 lib (probably used by the lottie library) is newer then your build-tools version. Try raising your build-tools version to 26.0.1 and your compile sdkVersion to 26.
Plus you are additionally trying to use the same library in an older version 
(compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1') could also be a problem.

And google moved it's repositories to a new location. When you use android gradle plugin > 3 just add this to your build-script

```
repositories {
    google()
}
```

else add this

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting this error after updating my gradle:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46443975/manifest-merger-failed-with-multiple-errors-while-updating-to-api-26-in-android/