# Manifest merger failed with multiple errors while updating to API 26 in android

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I tried updating my gradle with API 26 (**Android Studio 2.3.3**). But I am getting the following error while compiling the project.

**Here is the screenshot of the error I am getting:**

[image]

Application level `build.gradle`:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.5.0"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**This is my `Merged Manifest`:**
[image]

**If I remove `tools:replace="android:value"` from the `application` tag. I am getting below error.**

[image]
This is my `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ignite.a01hw909350.kolamdemo"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    aaptOptions {
        noCompress 'KARMarker'
        noCompress 'armodel'
    }

}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile project(':KudanAR')
    compile "com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.2"
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'nl.dionsegijn:konfetti:1.0.2'
    compile 'me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.4.1'
    compile 'io.palaima:smoothbluetooth:0.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.3.0'
    compile 'com.flurgle:camerakit:0.9.17'
    compile 'com.github.zhukic:sectioned-recyclerview:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.4.3'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.4.0'
    compile 'org.rajawali3d:rajawali:1.1.668@aar'
    compile 'com.tapadoo.android:alerter:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.github.GoodieBag:ProtractorView:v1.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.stepstone.stepper:material-stepper:3.3.0'
    compile 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.4.3'
    compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.4'
    compile 'com.github.apl-devs:appintro:v4.2.2'
    compile 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.2.5'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

This is my `Manifest.xml` file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.ignite.a01hw909350.kolamdemo">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <supports-screens android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="320" />
    <supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <application
        android:name=".AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        tools:replace="android:value"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!-- <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/> -->
        <activity
            android:name=".ARCameraActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" />
        <activity
            android:name=".RegistrationActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

            <!-- android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"> -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MenuActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ScanAndDrawActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".GalleryActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".PdfKolamActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <service
            android:name=".BluetoothService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.ignite.a01hw909350.kolamdemo.BluetoothService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name=".MyScheduleReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".BotDialogActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity android:name=".ModelActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".PanchangActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".LoadLevelActivity" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".MyStartServiceReceiver"
            android:exported="true" />

        <service
            android:name=".services.AlarmService"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="NOTIFICATION_SERVICE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name=".BootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity android:name=".CurrentPanchangActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".FragmentDemoActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".VideoPlayerActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
        <activity android:name=".IntroActivity"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have also added the new url in my application level gradle which google has recently introduced.

What is the problem in my Manifest.xml. I never got such error before updating to API 26. **What can be the possible solution for this?**

Comment: There is tab in bottom with "Merged Manifest" in you manifest file. You can check the error there.

Comment: try to remove     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

Comment: @Anjali why..???

Comment: I need that permission @Anjali

Comment: in Merged Manifest you have error on Right pannel. Fix that

Comment: can you show all details in the tab where you get this info "Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'"

Comment: I thing these error comes when there is some problem in your App menifiest file like Extras character or same activity tag define two times etc 

did you change something in manifest file before this? if yes then just try to undo that change and try ones again

Comment: No I didnt change anything. If i revert back to API 25 everything works fine. This error is only coming when I am updating to API 26. @sushantgosavi

Comment: Updated the question. @sushantgosavi

Answer (score 0):

Add below line in your manifest file's **application tag**

```
tools:replace="android:value"
```

Comment: @Hiren: try to set API 26 in both your application gradle file and your library's (*KudanAR*) gradle file

Comment: Updated the question with the new `Merged Manifest` error

Comment: If I add `tools:replace="android:value"` I am getting some different error. If I am removing that then its asking me to add the above line. Please check the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

If you concentrate a little bit you can find the solution, It said that the `READ_PHONE_STATE` is duplicated delete one of them and it said to add `tools:replace="android:value"` to you application tag at the manifest. Then clean and rebuild your project

Comment: with the same issues ?

Comment: Updated the question with the latest `Merged Manifest` error @Oussemaaroua

Comment: try to inject `tools:replace="android:value"` directly to the manifest tag

Comment: tried but didnt work @Oussemaaroua .getting same error.

Comment: try to use this `tools:replace="android:icon,android:label,android:theme, android:value"`

Comment: Same issue :( @Oussemaaroua

Comment: I updated the question with the error. Please check it. Added the error image.

Comment: add the `tools:replace="android:value"` inside the metadata tag

Comment: `<meta-data android:name="" tools:replace="android:value"/>` should I add this in my manifest ? what should be the name of the meta-data tag.

Comment: sorry my fault i was thinking that you declare sdk at the manifest, there is a conflict between libs try to check that all your libs are adapted with api26.

Comment: Update supportLibraryVersion in the application build.gradle to 26.0.2